# Why do running hardhat tasks in javascript require a colon?

Tags: etherscan, hardhat, verify

I am running `hardhat-etherscan` to auto verify smart contracts after deploying them.

[According to the documentation](https://hardhat.org/plugins/nomiclabs-hardhat-etherscan.html#providing-libraries-from-a-script-or-task), you add a little colon in between the word `verify` and add the word `verify` again.

```js
const { run } = require("hardhat")
.
.
.
await run("verify:verify")
```

...Why do we need to add the colon?

Answer (score 2):

There are various different parameters you can pass to the `verify` task to make it do different things, `verify` (meaning actually just do a verification) being one of them - see [`constants.ts`](https://github.com/NomicFoundation/hardhat/blob/767f68dee84d6a47cd40153a8ab8552f41a95d5e/packages/hardhat-etherscan/src/constants.ts#L6):

```
export const TASK_VERIFY_GET_MINIMUM_BUILD = "verify:get-minimum-build";
export const TASK_VERIFY_GET_CONSTRUCTOR_ARGUMENTS =
  "verify:get-constructor-arguments";
export const TASK_VERIFY_GET_COMPILER_VERSIONS = "verify:get-compiler-versions";
export const TASK_VERIFY_GET_ETHERSCAN_ENDPOINT =
  "verify:get-etherscan-endpoint";
export const TASK_VERIFY_GET_CONTRACT_INFORMATION =
  "verify:get-contract-information";
export const TASK_VERIFY_VERIFY_MINIMUM_BUILD = "verify:verify-minimum-build";
export const TASK_VERIFY_VERIFY = "verify:verify";
export const TASK_VERIFY_GET_LIBRARIES = "verify:get-libraries";
```

(It's presumably just doing a string comparison somewhere - they could have probably left out the colon and used a space, etc.?)

Comment: So I found this, and thanks for the info - but what do some of those others do? Like `verify:get-minimum-build`, what does that do?

Comment: I think some of them will be related to the parameters passed to the Etherscan contract verification API. For example, the constructor arguments (`get-constructor-arguments`) are optional parameters (see https://docs.etherscan.io/tutorials/verifying-contracts-programmatically). Poking around at the code, the `get-minimum-build` flag will cause only the target contract to be sent to the verification API, and will strip out any other contracts that are also in the current project directory that you probably don't want to be verified at the same time (which I think used to happen by default).